# Android: Could not load emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been trying to use the android emulator but it fails to start showing the message:[image] [image]

I could not really make out the error...can someone please suggest what should be done. I'm working with eclipse mars on linux mint 17.
Thanks.